# Mount smb shares in Ubuntu core

Tags: samba, ubuntu-core

Hi is there a way I can mount a smb share on boot in Ubuntu core. I can mount the share using the classic snap, but that doesn't do anything on boot and it won't mount at all in the standard Ubuntu core cli it just says can't mount read only share. My aim is to provide a larger storage location for my rocket chat instance but I'm setup on a pi with a small sd card.

Comment: I don't know about core, but did you try to `sudo mount -t cifs....[mount options]` from cli?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. Yes I've tried that, thats what gives the can't mount read only share error outside of the classic snap.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should install cifs-utils first and than add an entry to your /etc/fstab like this:

```
//ipofyourmachine/sharedfolder /mnt/share/ cifs username=user,password=pass,defaults 0 0
```

Edit:

Create share.mount in /etc/systemd/system

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/share.mount
```

Then paste this and adjust with your IP and folder directory names. Also, user and pass refer to the username and password of an account that has enough privileges to access the folders of the samba share.

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount unit for data

[Mount]
What=//192.168.1.1/shared
Where=/mnt/share
Type=cifs
Options=username=user,password=pass

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable and start the daemon:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable share.mount
sudo systemctl start share.mount
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you response, that doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu core. fstab doesn't have an effect in boot and can't be edited outside of the classic snap. I've got my fstab set up like above but it doesn't do anything on boot. It only seems to work with such mount -a when running the classic snap.

Comment: @rohtua I fixed the answer, I thought you were using a regular Ubuntu Server or desktop, now this should work for Core

Comment: Hi I've just tried your suggestion and it's acting in the same way as fstab. It won't work unless I'm in the sudo classic snap. It won't let me create any files in /etc/systemd/system either as my user, via sudo or as root. The folder I setup for the mount point is deleted on every reboot and creating the share.mount in the classic environment is stuck inside the snap so when I exit the file isn't accessible to the rest of the system and has no effect on boot/reboot (plus I can't actually enable it in the classic snap systemd gives a chroot ignoring request error!!!)

Comment: using @CristianVrinceanu example, I was able to get this working on ubuntu core 22 with an synology nas.  I had to add vers=2.0  to the options

Comment: Also had to add After/Wants=network-online.target